# Unity 3d player controller that can walk on walls?

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d

I'm creating a game where you can play as an ant and can walk on any surface. The problem is that I'm really new with unity and can't seem to be able to find a code that can do this. thanks!

Comment: Im not going to google it but there are youtube videos from unity demonstrating exactly how to do this.

Answer (score -1):

I would go with something such as this:

make walkable surfaces with the tag "walkable", and apply it to walls etc.
make your ant not affected by gravity when interacting with one, or change your gravity direction to be perpendicular to the wall.